# use of malloc and strtok of a 2d array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, strtok

This program is supposed to take `num` of arrays(in the file) and names(first, last, initial) of a 2d array. However I keep getting a seg fault and I do not know why. What I did was to allocate memory and then use `fscanf` to get number of lines and `fgets` to get names meanwhile changing all the `'\n'` to `'\0'`. Then, I use `strtok` to get separate array into token where I believe I could be wrong somewhere.

EDIT:Now I am getting  passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast.
How am I gonna fix it

This is my code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int num;
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

   fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);

   int j;
   char **f, **l, *m;
   int i = 0;

   f = (char**) malloc(num * sizeof (char*))


   for (i = 0; i < num;i++)
       ;
   f[i] = (char*) malloc(num * sizeof (char));
   l = (char**)malloc(num*sizeof(char*));

   for (i=0; i<num;i++)


   l[i] = (char*) malloc(num * sizeof (char));

   m = (char*) malloc(num*sizeof(char));

   read_names(fp, f, l, m, num);

//  sort(fp, num, f, l, m);
//  display(num, ar);

   for (j = 0; j < num; j++) {
       free(f[j]);
       free(l[j]); 
   }

   free(f);
   free(l);
   free(m);
   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}

     void read_names (FILE *fp, char **f, char **l, char m,int num)
     {
     int i=0;

    char temp[80];


    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {  fgets(temp, 80,fp );
    char *ptr=strtok (temp,"," );
    strcpy(*f[i], ptr);
    char *ptr1=strtok (temp, " ");
    strcpy(*l[i], ptr1);
    char *ptr2=strtok (temp, ". ");
    strcpy(m[i],ptr2);
}

    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Each first/last name has num bytes allocated.  Are you sure that the length of names should match the number of names to be read from file?

Comment: Also a strategy to debug segfaults is to put in extra `return`s in your function until the segfault disappears. Eventually you will find roughly on which line the segfault happens.

Comment: Paul R has a very good point.

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with your for loops. Instead of enclosing the line below them, you are terminating the for() loops with a semicolon. Remove the semicolon, or perhaps better, get in the habit of always using `{` and `}` and you will not have this problem again.

Edit:
had you indented your code properly, you might have spotted the error just by that.

Comment: Of course, using braces won't actually prevent this as `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++); { printf ("Run once\n"); }` is still valid C, will still compile, and will still only print once.

Comment: yes, but if you indent properly and take the habit of always using {} with if/else/while/do etc, then you are less likely to make this mistake, is what I am arguing. Heck, indenting alone might have prevented it. Which brings me to one of my pet peeves - in the name of "liberty" (or compiler convenience?) we leave developers to make the same mistakes all over again. Mandatory formatting on check-in ftw I say...

Answer (score 1):

```
f=(char**)malloc (num*sizeof(char*));
for (i=0; i<num;i++);
f[i]=(char*)malloc (num*sizeof(char));

l=(char**)malloc (num*sizeof(char*));
for (i=0; i<num;i++);
l[i]=(char*)malloc (num*sizeof(char));

m=(char*)malloc (num*sizeof(char));
```

You should make sure that f,f[i],l,l[i] are not NULL.